# Left Inner Join 5 tables

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to left inner join 5 tables. I SELECT 4 columns, then I wrote

```
FROM table_a 
LEFT INNER JOIN table_b 
LEFT INNER JOIN table_c 
LEFT INNER JOIN table_d 
ON table_a.a = table_b.a, 
table_b.c=table_c.c, 
table_c.b=table_d.b
```

But when I try to run this on SQL in Access 2007, it tells me there is an error in the FROM code. I have really no idea what I am doing wrong.

Thanks for any help you can give me.

Comment: There is no such thing as a `left inner join`, it's a `left outer join` or an `inner join`

Comment: That's not how to write a join... Try [this](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MS Access requires parentheses around joins:

```
FROM ((table_a LEFT JOIN
       table_b
       ON table_a.a = table_b.a
      ) LEFT INNER JOIN
      table_c
      ON table_b.c = table_c.c
     ) LEFT JOIN
     table_d
     ON table_c.b = table_d.b
```

If you intend `INNER JOIN` then replace `LEFT JOIN` with `INNER JOIN`.

In addition:

- There is no such thing as `LEFT INNER JOIN`.
- MS Access uses `LEFT JOIN` for a left outer join.
- You should put the `ON` clause immediately after the table/subquery after the `JOIN`.
- Parentheses are needed for both inner and outer joins.

Comment: @nola94 . . . You should study up on SQL if you want to write `SELECT` queries.  That is the best advice I can give you.